# installing Lingotip translate on Magento; php version conflict; would like to override

Tags: php, magento, pear, conflict

I have just installed Magento ver. 1.4.1.1 on our Ubuntu dev server and am trying to install the [Lingotip translation extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/specs/4331/lingotip_translate).

I am receiving the error:

```
magento-community/Lingotip_Translate requires PHP (version >= 5.0, version <= 5.3.2), installed version is 5.3.2-2
Install Errors
No valid packages found
PEAR ERROR: install failed
```

I think there must be a fairly simple way to comment out this check code to allow the .2-2 patch to work, but I am completely new to Magento and am unable to find it anywhere in the codebase.

My question is, can someone show me either:

1) how to "override" this blocking code, or

2) how to install this "ready2paste" version of the lingotip code I found at the freegentoo site.

Thank you!

Comment: tried to fix your second link, but google has no idea what you're talking about :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Magento is certified for PHP 5.3  There are a slew of issues with 5.3 on the Magento forums, the fixes involve hacking the core Magento code which isn't recommended.

I would suggest that you rollback to PHP 5.2 which will fix your immediate issue and be safer with Magento in general.

--------- EDIT ---------

If rollback to 5.2 isn't an option, you could download the package manually using

```
./pear download magento-community/Lingotip_Translate
```

and then exploding the tarball yourself.  Place the `app`, `skin` and other folders as seems appropriate and go for it.  Obviously, you are choosing to void your warranty in bypassing the installer, and your mileage may vary.  good luck :)

You will need to have run `./pear mage-setup .` in your magento install dir previously.

Comment: thanks, but that's not really necessary or an option - we simply want to see how this extension is working to consider an integration with one of our products. We aren't really Magento users, we are simply learning about this functionality. Magento itself is running fine for what we need.

Comment: thank you jonathan! so, these files go into the existing top level dirs, rather than some subdirectory (as would, say, a Wordpress theme)?  I did run mage-setup when i installed, so should be good there. really just trying to get this set up so we can look at how it works - ok if the rest of magento collapses in on itself :-)

Comment: yup, merge the tarball files in the `app`, `skin` and `js` folders into those respective folders in the magento install. Looks like the `lti_client_calls.php` file goes in the root dir which is a bit messy...

Comment: by the way, feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer if it works for you, that's the stackoverflow way :)

Comment: hi jonathan, sorry - was waiting to see if that got it up and running. it DID answer my question (so I'll Accept), but not quite up and running...if you don't mind, if I am unable to get it working today, I'll PM you and then post a final answer here for others (rather than carrying on a long conversation in this area)

Comment: and the final step - flush the cache :-)   thank you for your help

Comment: @jmadsen - hehe, cache gets 'em everytime :) I'd be interested to get that PM to know how it goes, I may use that Lingo service myself.